# How to vertically center an element, that has a float, with CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this article list loop

```
  <article class="article <?php if($i%2==0) { echo 'even'; } else { echo 'odd'; } ?>">
    <section class="container">
      <section class="content">

        <h2><?= $r['title'] ?></h2>
        <span class="subtitle"><?= $r['subtitle'] ?>&nbsp;</span>

        <section class="text">
          <?= $r['text'] ?>
        </section>

      </section>


      <section class="image">
        <img src="<?= $img ?>" alt="<?= $img ?>" class="img-responsive article-image" />
      </section>
    </section>
  </article>
```

and I'd like to center the image to be at the middle, at all times, with the `.content`. So that `image margin-top` is like

`(content.height()-image.height())/2`

I tried jQuery for this and for whatever the reason, `$('.image').closest($('.content'))` didn't work for me so it always selected the first `.content` and adjusted `margin-top` based on that.

If you can show me a jQuery or CSS approach on how to do this, that'd be great. I tried several ways of doing that with CSS, but none of them worked because all of my elements have a float (`image` and `content` are located horizontally next to each other).

**EDIT**: http://jsfiddle.net/hwx5Lsvz/

Comment: And post a fiddle with a sample item as to what it looks like.

Comment: @LShetty posted a fiddle

Comment: Step one, remove the float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position),

> A floating box must be placed as high as possible.

But you can remove float and use

```css
.content, .image {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#list_articles {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#list_articles .article {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 80px 0;
  position: relative;
}
#list_articles .even {
  background: #fff;
}
#list_articles .odd {
  background: transparent;
}
#list_articles .article .content {
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}
#list_articles .article .image {
  width: 40%;
}
#list_articles .article h2 {
  color: #184180;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
}
#list_articles .article .subtitle {
  color: #5271a0;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#list_articles .article .text {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.content,
.image {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<section id="list_articles">
  <article class="article">
    <section class="container">
      <section class="content">
        <h2>Here's a title</h2>
        <span class="subtitle">Here's a subtitle &nbsp;</span>
        <section class="text">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat consequat nunc, vel pellentesque elit maximus non. Aliquam eu interdum purus. Suspendisse venenatis finibus sem in ornare. Cras volutpat aliquam tincidunt. Sed massa tortor, consectetur id nulla auctor, porttitor mattis mi. Cras feugiat augue eget urna fermentum, nec venenatis tellus auctor. In pretium consectetur purus, id finibus diam tincidunt eget. Donec nec tincidunt ante. Donec elementum tincidunt faucibus. Aliquam volutpat nibh ornare enim sagittis efficitur. Maecenas convallis consectetur nulla quis ultrices. Nam dolor justo, vehicula a laoreet at, tincidunt eu lacus. Fusce hendrerit velit a convallis dictum. Etiam dignissim, odio at fringilla aliquam, libero dui hendrerit tortor, eu blandit lectus leo ut nulla.
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="image">
        <img src="http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg" class="img-responsive article-image" />
      </section>
    </section>
  </article>
</section>
```